# Regex is causing an error that I can't seem to find

Tags: python, regex, search

The code below worked fine until I added the regex line. When I comment it out, the code works again ... I'm stumped. I'm only using a regex to search a file for three different type of strings concurrently(ascii, hex, string). Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
 elif searchType =='2':
          print "  Directory to be searched: c:\Python27 "
          directory = os.path.join("c:\\","Python27")
          userstring = raw_input("Enter a string name to search: ")
          userStrHEX = userstring.encode('hex')
          userStrASCII = ' '.join(str(ord(char)) for char in userstring)
          regex = re.compile( "(%s|%s|%s)" % ( re.escape( userstring ), re.escape( userStrHEX ), re.escape( userStrASCII ) )
          for root,dirname, files in os.walk(directory):
             for file in files:
                 if file.endswith(".log") or file.endswith(".txt"):
                    f=open(os.path.join(root, file))
                    for line in f.readlines():
                       #if userstring in line:
                       if regex.search(line):       
                          print "file: " + os.path.join(root,file)           
                          break
                    else:
                       print "String NOT Found!"
                       break
                    f.close()
```

Comment: I'm not a Python person but is your indentation correct here? for example, should the final `else` be relating to the final `if`?

Comment: which line in particular are you asking about? the `regex = re.compile...` line? if that's not present, is the `if regex.search(line):` also absent?

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @El Ronnoco: The `else` clause after `for` is executed if the `for` ran to completion (without `break`ing out). It makes sense as it is used here.

Comment: @Emil if the regex = re.compile ... is not present, there is no error

Comment: @Bryan Oakley ... "invalid syntax", but I'm not seeing anything erroneous.

Comment: @user706608: first rule of debugging: assume the error message is telling the truth. If it says you have a syntax error on a line, then you have a syntax error on that line. In the absence of anything more specific, the first thing to do is count braces and quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I ran this code, I got an error like

```
File "search.py", line 7
    for root,dirname, files in os.walk(directory):
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is because the previous line, which contains the compiled regular expression, is missing a closing parentheses:

```
regex = re.compile( "(%s|%s|%s)" % ( re.escape( userstring ), re.escape( userStrHEX ), re.escape( userStrASCII ) )
```

should read

```
regex = re.compile( "(%s|%s|%s)" % ( re.escape( userstring ), re.escape( userStrHEX ), re.escape( userStrASCII ) ) )
```

Comment: I wear glasses, and I didn't see that thanks ... still blind.